# Assigning grep result string to a variable in Windows batch file

Tags: batch-file

In a batch file, I can send the results from grep to a file like this:

```
grep -o -P -f search_text.txt text_file.txt >outputfile.txt
```

But I don't want the result to go to a file. I want the result to be stored in a variable that I can use later in the batch file. I want to do this:

```
grep -o -P -f search_text.txt text_file.txt >my_variable
```

But of course that doesn't work. How can I get grep results assigned to a variable?

Comment: Use a `for /f` loop to capture the result of a command to a variable.  `help for` from a console window for more info.  Basically, `for /f "delims=" %%I in ('grep -Pof needle.txt haystack.txt') do set "variable=%%I"`

Answer (score 0):

grep -o -P -f search_text.txt text_file.txt >outputfile.txt

then do

var=$(head -n 1 outputfile.txt)
(read first line)

and you have the result in var

Comment: Yes, this will work, but it turns out that it defeats the reason I wanted the grep results to go to a variable in the first place. I am trying to reduce file I/O by grepping all my results, storing the results into variables, and only writing to a file once at the end.

Answer (score 0):

tmpStr=`grep -o -P -f search_text.txt text_file.txt`

if it won't work, try :

tmpStr=$(grep -o -P -f search_text.txt text_file.txt)